# Has anyone used Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) and if so does it have standard SMTP configuration?

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ses

We want to use the more advanced features of Amazon SES such as their API for having better control and visibility over emails. However I also want it to work OOB with our current system which is simply a username/password and SMTP URI. Is that still possible with Amazon SES or will everything have to be an HTTP Post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon SES will require you to use their API, so I believe everything will have to be an HTTP Post.

Are you against integrating an API into your application?

**EDIT:** Found a [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/229491/how-can-i-make-amazon-ses-the-default-method-of-sending-mail-from-my-server). Let me know if that works.

Comment: Not at all, it's just about renewal timing. Right now we are up for renewal with our current SMTP provider and want to make the jump immediately without development effort. And then add the more advanced features later.

Comment: Whoop, okay, found a solution on Serverfault, check my edit!

Answer (score 4):

Amazon just released SMTP access to SES and it's not too difficult to setup now. Here's a howto that I wrote this morning with details on setting it up:  http://www.millcreeksys.com/2011/12/14/how-to-configure-your-postfix-server-to-relay-email-through-amazon-simple-email-service-ses/

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I don't want to have to develop any wrappers or extra code to use amazon ses with our forum (which uses smtp) and after quite a bit of browsing, I came across this (http://computerone.co.nz/community/discussion/33/amazon-simple-email-ses-smtp-relay-service).

Once I got my production account for ses, I just put in my aws keys, verified my forum email address and changed the settings. It took literally less than a minute once I got my aws production access from amazon, as long as you follow their instructions. In the long term I will probably end up integrating ses with iss but for now it works fine.